# SQL that returns all 10 way (!!!) combinations of a summed column

Tags: sql

Bear with me, I'm approaching this one thought at a time, which started here at this question I posted:

[SQL that returns all the permutations of a summed column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140558/sql-that-returns-all-the-permutations-of-a-summed-column/44140629?noredirect=1#44140558)

So, to re-hash, Let's say we have the following data:

```
ID VALUE
-- -----
1  60
2  60
3  60
4  60
```

And I wanted to find all the permutations of records that SUM to 120. Meaning, the results would be 6 rows:

```
1 AND 2
1 AND 3
1 AND 4
--2 AND 1 (already used)
2 AND 3
2 AND 4
--3 AND 1 (already used)
--3 AND 2 (already used)
3 AND 4
```

The solutions provided, on these two-way combinations was to perform a self join.

But, I'm thinking that solution wouldn't apply to what I'm really seeking:  10-way combinations (on data that doesn't sum as easily as my contrived example).

Is this even possible (with some simple SQL)?

Let me elaborate some more:

Data:

```
ID VALUE
-- -----
1  40
2  63
3  19
4  82
... and may more records
```

Results I'm looking for (all combinations of 10 records that add up to at least 300):

So like the first, where it was:

```
1 AND 2
1 AND 3
... etc
```

But now we are dealing with 10, so the results might look like (for an expected sum of > 300 but < 400):

```
ID1 DUR1 ID2 DUR2 ID3 DUR3 ... ID10 DUR10 SUMMED_TOTAL
--- ---- --- ---- --- ----     ---- ----- ------------
 1   40   2   63   3   19       23   8     312
 1   40   2   63   4   82       29   11    323
```

Comment: do you mean 10 combinations summing up to some number?what should the output look like?

Comment: I'll re-edit the question, though I'm surprised people are giving me a hard-time and down-voting my question, especially when it was suggested by a mod here to start a second follow-up question.  Holy cow.

Comment: What are `10-way combinations`? Can you give an example of that? Find 10 datasets that return a specified value if summed up?

Comment: Well, I said permutations previously, but was corrected, in my other thread, and was told it was "combinations".  The question posed to me, from a co-worker, was a SQL that gave me all examples of 10 records that have a duration equal to 5 minutes (this is a duration field).  So there would be 21 columns in each row?  (ID1, duration1, ID2, duration 2, ID3, duration3, ..... ID10, duration10, "summed duration equal to 5 mins")

Comment: Getting all combinations should be rather easy. Just join the table 10 times with itself. The tricky part will be to find a logic to remove "duplicate" combinations. You might be able to identify duplicate combinations by taking the sum of all 10 ID column in a dataset. This might create a unique value that you could group by. Not sure this works though, as I'm not mathematically sound enough to proof (or disproof) that this will actually be a unique value that can't be achieved my summing other combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a recursive CTE, this essentially performs the inner join used in your last question, but will keep repeating the join until there are no more combinations.

For a quick Demo I have used values of (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 128) so that for any number between 1 and 255, there is only one combination to reduce duplicated rows:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Value INT);
INSERT @T (ID, Value) 
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 8), (5, 16), (6, 32), (7, 64), (8, 128);

WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ID,
            IDsUsed = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ID),
            Value,
            ValuesUsed = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Value),
            ItemCount = 1
    FROM    @T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  T.ID,
            IDsUsed = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONCAT(CTE.IDsUsed, ',', T.ID)),
            Value = CTE.Value + T.Value,
            ValuesUsed = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONCAT(CTE.ValuesUsed, ',', T.Value)),
            ItemCount = ItemCount + 1
    FROM    CTE
            INNER JOIN @T AS T
                ON T.ID > CTE.ID
)
SELECT  IDsUsed, ValuesUsed, Value, ItemCount
FROM    CTE
WHERE   Value = 3
```

So for 255 you get:

```
IDsUsed             ValuesUsed              Value       ItemCount
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8     1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128    255             8
```

For 3 you would get:

```
IDsUsed         ValuesUsed          Value       ItemCount
--------------------------------------------------------------
1,2             1,2                 3               2
```

**EDIT**

I think I may have mis understood your requirements. If you want to find out the total of 10 combinations exactly, then you need to use 10 joins exactly. It is pretty long winded, but gives you what you want.

```
SELECT  ID1 = t1.ID,
        Value1 = t1.Value,
        ID2 = t2.ID,
        Value2 = t2.Value,
        ID3 = t3.ID,
        Value3 = t3.Value,
        ID4 = t4.ID,
        Value4 = t4.Value,
        ID5 = t5.ID,
        Value5 = t5.Value,
        ID6 = t6.ID,
        Value6 = t6.Value,
        ID7 = t7.ID,
        Value7 = t7.Value,
        ID8 = t8.ID,
        Value8 = t8.Value,
        ID9 = t9.ID,
        Value9 = t9.Value,
        ID10 = t10.ID,
        Value10 = t10.Value,
        Total = t1.Value + t2.Value + t3.Value + t4.Value + t5.Value + 
                t6.Value + t7.Value + t8.Value + t9.Value + t10.Value
FROM    YourTable AS t1
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS t2
            ON t2.ID > t1.ID
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS t3
            ON t3.ID > t2.ID
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS t4
            ON t4.ID > t3.ID
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS t5
            ON t5.ID > t4.ID
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS t6
            ON t6.ID > t5.ID
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS t7
            ON t7.ID > t6.ID
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS t8
            ON t8.ID > t7.ID
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS t9
            ON t9.ID > t8.ID
        INNER JOIN YourTable AS t10
            ON t10.ID > t9.ID
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time.  Yeah, that's pretty gnarly, and from the execution of this query, it takes a lot of time, so I don't think it's a production solution, but a solution that answers my question.  Green check mark!

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with it whatsoever, but I believe [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) is more geared up to these kind of statistical problems than SQL Server. I can't offer any further help than that, but it might be something worth reading up about.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
select id1,id2
from (select t1.id as id1,t2.id as id2,
      count(*) over(partition by t1.id) as cnt,
      t1.val+sum(t2.val) over(partition by t1.id) as total
      from t t1
      join t t2 on t1.id<t2.id
     ) x
where cnt = 9 and total>=300
```

Comment: you should understand that this returns the same results as the other answer, without 10 joins..but in a row-wise way.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll play around with it some more, actually.

Comment: I am not sure it does return the same results - http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e1b1ebd3f191540d58eddc6375b8ae3b Could you possibly add an explanation to the answer so that it is more clear how it works?